# How to add parameters to my query using sqlsrv in php?

Tags: php, sql-injection, sqlsrv

I am trying to pass a parameter to my query to filter by client (chosen through a dropdown list). I am aware of SQL injections and would like to avoid using the parameter in my query string. Is there a way I could pass my parameter to the query without having to risk an sql injection?

```
//Function creates a connection between a query and a db table.
function createQueryConn($query)
{
    $GLOBALS['queryconn'] = sqlsrv_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $query, array(), array("Scrollable" => 'static'));
}


class CONNECTDB
{
// Creates connection to the database using sqlsrv.
    public function dbConnection()
    {
        $servername = "bl3c7b";
        $connectionInfo = array("Database" => "dashboard_das", "UID" => "test", "PWD" => "test",'ReturnDatesAsStrings'=>true);
        $GLOBALS['conn'] = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $connectionInfo);
        if (!$GLOBALS['conn']) {
            echo "Error connecting to database.";
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }
    }
}

// Call DB connection.
$Connection = new CONNECTDB();
$Connection->dbConnection();

// Function gets activities per employee param.
function getActivityPerEmployee($employee)
{
    $WoNum = $Status  = null;
    $query = "SELECT [WONUM],[STATUS] FROM [dbo].[Activities] act
    WHERE YEAR(SCHEDSTART)=2019
    AND
    [STATUS] not like 'CLOSED'
    AND
    DATEDIFF(dd,SCHEDSTART,SCHEDFINISH) < 30
    and OWNER like '$employee'
    order by [OWNER] ASC";

    createQueryConn($query);
    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($GLOBALS['queryconn']);
    if ($rows === false) {
    } else {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($GLOBALS['queryconn'], SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            ConvertData($row["WONUM"],$row["STATUS"]);
        }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Driver for SQL Server supports the execution of parameterized queries by using [sqlsrv_query()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-2017) or [sqlsrv_prepare()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-prepare?view=sql-server-2017) \ [sqlsrv_execute()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-execute?view=sql-server-2017) functions.

> The sqlsrv_query function is well-suited for one-time queries and
>   should be the default choice to execute queries unless special
>   circumstances apply. This function provides a streamlined method to
>   execute a query with a minimum amount of code. The sqlsrv_query
>   function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and
>   can be used to execute parameterized queries.
>
> ...
>
> The combination of
>   sqlsrv_prepare and sqlsrv_execute separates statement preparation and
>   statement execution in to two function calls and can be used to
>   execute parameterized queries. This function is ideal to execute a
>   statement multiple times with different parameter values for each
>   execution.

If you want to execute a parameterized query, follow the next steps:

- Define a placeholders in the SQL statement using question marks (`?`).
- Initialize an array of parameter values which correspond to parameter placeholders.

The following example is based on your code and demonstrates how to execute a parameterized query:

```
<php

...
function getActivityPerEmployee($employee)
{
    $WoNum = $Status  = null;
    $query = "
        SELECT [WONUM],[STATUS] 
        FROM [dbo].[Activities] act
        WHERE 
            YEAR(SCHEDSTART)=2019 AND
            [STATUS] not like 'CLOSED' AND
            DATEDIFF(dd,SCHEDSTART,SCHEDFINISH) < 30 and 
            OWNER LIKE '%' + ? + '%'
            -- or without LIKE
            -- OWNER = ? 
        order by [OWNER] ASC
    ";

    $GLOBALS['queryconn'] = sqlsrv_query(
        $GLOBALS['conn'], 
        $query, 
        array($employee), 
        array("Scrollable" => 'static')
    );
    if ($GLOBALS['queryconn'] === false) {
        echo "Error: ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }

    $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows($GLOBALS['queryconn']);
    if ($rows === false) {
    } else {
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($GLOBALS['queryconn'], SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
}
...
?>
```