# Insert Arabic values in SqlServer 2019 using php

Tags: php, sql-server, arabic, sqldatatypes, sqlsrv

I want to insert arabic values, so i used this syntax :

```
$sql = "
    insert into sdka_creation (creation_time, sdka_for, creator_ip)
    values ('$creation_time',N\'$name\', '$creator_ip')
";
```

// or N"$name"

this gives me this error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: sqlsrv_rows_affected(): Argument #1 ($stmt) must be of type resource, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\quran\go.php:443 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\quran\go.php(443): sqlsrv_rows_affected(false) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\quran\go.php on line 443

and other time :

```
$fnmae = N'$name';
$sql = "
    insert into sdka_creation (creation_time, sdka_for, creator_ip)
    values ('$creation_time','$fname', '$creator_ip')
";
```

this gives me synatx error :

> Syntax error: unexpected token ''$name''

how could be solved ?

Note : db type is nvarchar

summary (all of these errors) :

```
 $sql = "
     insert into sdka_creation (creation_time, sdka_for, creator_ip)
     values ('$creation_time',N\'$name\', '$creator_ip')
 ";
```

and :

```
$fnmae = N'$name';
```

Comment: Why are you injecting and not parametrising? That is the *real* problem.

Comment: Not that it's the solution, because the solution is to parametrise, but this is great proof of why spelling your object/variable names correctly is important. It's *name* not *nmae*, and therefore `$fnmae` <> `$fname`.

Comment: i corrected it .. same error appears

Comment: Again, *parametrise*. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: what excatly should be parametrized .. my code work successfully when delete N'  ' .. POV is this .. every parameters and spellngs is ok

Comment: *"what excatly should be parametrized"* Your variables. `values ('$creation_time','$fname'`, for example, is **injecting** the values from your PHP variables `$creation_time` and `$fname`; this is a **dangerous** and *fatal* security flaw.

Comment: how to be solved ?

Comment: It's solved by **using parameters**. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57313946/how-to-add-parameters-to-my-query-using-sqlsrv-in-php as well as the PHP manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php . This can help with syntax problems, encoding problems, and also means you are not vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com) attacks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)